# How can I make a PHP script that turns certain HTML text into entities?

Tags: php, html, html-entities

I'm a beginner in PHP
I want to make a PHP script that replace certain values inside the attributes of the tag into HTML entities.

like this:

```
<body>
<img src="&#x68;&#x74;&#x74;&#x70;&#x73;&#x3A;&#x2F;&#x2F;&#x70;&#x6C;&#x61;&#x63;&#x65;&#x69;&#x6D;&#x67;&#x2E;&#x63;&#x6F;&#x6D;&#x2F;&#x36;&#x34;&#x30;&#x2F;&#x34;&#x38;&#x30;&#x2F;&#x6E;&#x61;&#x74;&#x75;&#x72;&#x65;" alt="&#x47;&#x6F;&#x6F;&#x67;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x20;&#x57;&#x65;&#x62;&#x73;&#x69;&#x74;&#x65;" height="&#x34;&#x32;" width="&#x34;&#x32;">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the existing function :  htmlentities()

Manual link : http://php.net/htmlentities

Comment: htmlentities() turns all the text into entities but I want only to turn the values inside the attributes into entities.

Comment: As a programmer, you have to learn to think flexibly. You can do that: <img src="<?php echo htmlentities($text);?>" width="<?php echo htmlentities($width)" height="<?php echo htmlentities($height); ?>"